# How to find common rows based on multiple column values?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, comparison

I want to get the common rows between df1 and df2 according to two column conditions, which means that the rows are considered "common" if the value in these two columns are the same.
I also want to find the percentage of common rows from one df to the other in percentage.

For example I have these two dataframes:
[image]

```
import pandas as pd

data1 = {
    "first_column": ["id1", "id2", "id3"],
    "second_column": ["1", "2", "2"],
    "third_column": ["1", "2", "2"],
    "fourth_column": ["1", "2", "1"],
}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)

data2 = {
    "first_column": ["id1", "id2", "id3", "id4"],
    "second_column": ["3", "4", "2", "2"],
    "third_column": ["1", "2", "2", "2"],
    "fourth_column": ["1", "2", "2", "2"],
}

df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)
```

Expected output:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to do it:

```py
for df, other in ((df1, df2), (df2, df1)):
    # Keep copy of original dfs
    df_temp = df.copy()
    other_temp = other.copy()

    # Get names of df and other
    df_name = [key for key in globals() if globals()[key] is df][0]
    other_name = [key for key in globals() if globals()[key] is other][0]

    # Select rows with common ids
    df = df[df["first_column"].isin(other["first_column"])]
    other = other[other["first_column"].isin(df["first_column"])]

    # Find common values between df and other
    common_rows = df.loc[
        (df["first_column"] == other["first_column"])
        & (df["second_column"] == other["second_column"])
        & (df["third_column"] == other["third_column"]),
        :,
    ]
    print(
        f"\n{df_name} dataframe with common values according to second and third column"
    )
    print(common_rows)

    # Percentage of common values
    print(
        f"% of rows in {df_name} common with {other_name}: "
        + f"{round(100 * common_rows.shape[0] / df_temp.shape[0], 2)}"
    )
```

Output:

```
df1 dataframe with common values according to second and third column
  first_column second_column third_column fourth_column
2          id3             2            2             1
% of rows in df1 common with df2: 33.33

df2 dataframe with common values according to second and third column
  first_column second_column third_column fourth_column
2          id3             2            2             2
% of rows in df2 common with df1: 25.0
```